# How do I create a function that accepts any form of number?

Tags: c#

```
public static void AddCharToNum <I> (ref I OriginalNumber, char NumberToAdd_Char) where I : struct {

    double NumberToAdd = char.GetNumericValue (NumberToAdd_Char);

    OriginalNumber = OriginalNumber * 10 + (int) NumberToAdd;
}
```

It displays this error: Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type`I' and `int'

EDIT: The problem I'm trying to solve is this:

I don't want to repeat this code again and again:

```
switch (ParseState) {
case 1:
    {
    a = (a * 10) + char.GetNumericValue (NumberToAdd_Char);
    }

case 2:
    {
    x = (x * 10) + char.GetNumericValue (NumberToAdd_Char); //where x is a float
    }

case 3:
    {
    b = (b * 10) + char.GetNumericValue (NumberToAdd_Char); //where b is a double
    }

case 4:
    {
    c = (c * 10) + char.GetNumericValue (NumberToAdd_Char); //where c is an integer
    }
}
```

Comment: hoiw can you multiply a struct?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make this more complicated than it needs to be.  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Change from : 10 to : 10F

Comment: The only way that works is if you add a contraint to a specific type that overloads the multiply operator, but then you might as well not be using generics.  You might want to instead create overloads for all the types you want this to work for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to parse some string of digits into integer digit by digit, I'm right?
If that is the case simply use [int.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) or [int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding float number to the result anyway you might as well just use float or double variables. Also, it seems that your method logically returns number with additional character while having void return type. I would rewrite your method as follows:

```
public static double AddCharToNum (double originalNumber, char charToAdd) {
    double numberToAdd = char.GetNumericValue(charToAdd);
    return originalNumber * 10 + numberToAdd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using custom classes, which provice a numeric value. If so, you should make use of operator overloading.

> C# allows user-defined types to overload operators by defining static member functions using the operator keyword

Check this page for more informations: [MSDN: Overloadable Operators (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Here is a quick example:

```
public static I operator *(I first, int second)
{
    /* Pseudo code:
    var number = first.Value;
    I outVal = new I();
    outVal.Value = number * second;
    return outVal;
    */
}
```

## Edit:

When using these operators on different/generic types like "I" is. Make a variable **dynamic** before using operators.
Like this:

```
dynamic dynOriginalNumber = OriginalNumber;
OriginalNumber = (OriginalNumber)(dynOriginalNumber * 10 + (float) NumberToAdd);
```